# Irreducibility of a family of quintic polynomials with solvable Galois group order 20

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Consider quintic polynomials in the form $$f=T^{5}+2^{q}3^{4k+1}5^{4r+1}T+2^{5q+2}3^{5k+1}5^{5r}\quad q,k,r\in \Bbb N \tag{1}$$ whose discriminant is $\Delta=\left(2^{5+10q}3^{2+10k}5^{2+10r}\right)^{2}5\notin \Bbb Z^2$, not a square.

For example,$(q,k,r)=(0,0,0)$ gives $f=T^5=15T+12$. This family has unique real root, $f'>0$, and the splitting field contains $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)=\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)$). It is build by considering reduced quintics $T^5+AT+B$ whose sextic resolvent $R=\prod_{g\in S_5/F_{20}}(T-g\phi)$ has **zero** as rational root ($256A^{6}-9375AB^{4}=0$ gives this family), where the resolvent $\phi(x_0,\dots,x_4)=\sum x_{\sigma(i)}x_{\sigma(j)}x_{\sigma((i+j)/2}$ is stablized by the affine linear group $F_{20}$ of order $20$, as explained in Dummit's paper on solvable quintics, cf [Wiki Solvable Quintics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Other_solvable_quintics))

EDIT: the question was to show that the polynomials (1) are irreducible. Servaes proposed the transformation $3^{-5k}f(3^kT)=T^5 +2^{4q}\cdot 3\cdot 5^{4r+1}T+2^{5q+2}\cdot 3\cdot 5^{5r}$ that shows the polynomial is $3$-Eisenstein, so irreducible.

Comment: You're correct that $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_{19}$, but I'm not sure I follow you're reasoning ("but this is impossible since the splitting = stem field of $\bar f$ has degree 5")  Seems like that could be a bit circular.  Compare $x^5 + 2x^4 + 5x^3 + 8x^2 + 7x + 4$ over $\Bbb{F}_{5}$  This factors as $(x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x^2 + 3x + 4)$

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will delete and eventually correct the end.

Comment: How about applying Eisenstein to $3^{-5k}f(3^kT)$?

Comment: I tried quite a few combinations, but not this one!

Comment: Well done! $T^{5}+2^{4q}\cdot 3\cdot 5^{4r+1}T+2^{5q+2}\cdot 3\cdot 5^{5r}$ is $3$-Eisenstein indeed, so the rest of the post has no interest.